# Customize sencha app build process

Tags: extjs, build

I am creating an application using sencha and using MVVM universal code structuring.
I am not following default universal structure provided by sencha.
My sencha application folder structure is as follows:

- app

  - Application.js
  - locale (contain language related file)
  - utilities (contain common constant)
- common

  - classic

    - src
    - controller
    - model
    - view (contain main portal.js )
    - store
- jobmanagement

  - src

    - controller
    - model
    - view
    - store

I have set classpath in `app.json` as below :

```
"app",
"common/${toolkit.name}/src",
"common/src",
"jobmanagement/${toolkit.name}/src",
"jobmanagement/src"
```

after successful build process, all the jobmanagement related js files are not getting included in app.js in an encrypted format.

What changes I need to do to add jobmanagement in build process

Comment: You will need to include jobmanagement in app folder, because sencha does build process from app folder.Any specific reason why its kept outside ?

Comment: This is call is by architecture.

We are dividing application into separate task management.


Like in common folder application default layout and dynamic grid creation will come  and in jobmanagement all the jobs related data will come which will use common folder as parent to load its data.

Like wise in parallel with jobmanagenet , usermanagment and account managment will come with same folder structure

Comment: What changes we need to do in build files to get this folder structure working. As this folder structure is running while watch it should work for build also.

Comment: I included job-management folder in app and made the app.json changes as follows :

"app/jobmanagement/${toolkit.name}/src",
"app/jobmanagement/src"

still its not working

Comment: If it were some resources kind of thing then there is config in app.json named "resources".But you want that folder encrypted as app.js. But you can maintain same hierarchy inside app folder.

Comment: No its not resources. I need to follow same structure for architectural needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app.josn` file of your EXTJS's application you can specify `classpath` property.

```
 /**
     * Comma-separated string with the paths of directories or files to search. Any classes
     * declared in these locations will be available in your class "requires" or in calls
     * to "Ext.require". The "app.dir" variable below is expanded to the path where the
     * application resides (the same folder in which this file is located).
     */
    "classpath": [
        "app",
        "${toolkit.name}/src",
        "jobmanagement"
    ],
```

You also have to specify `'jobmanagement.*'` in `requires` section of `Ext.app.Application`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Required Ext js library component was not getting included  in app.js file during build.
So specify ' Ext.* ' in application.js
Thanks for help.